Identify unlabelled microcontroller in RJ Tianye battery charger
I am trying to identify, and hopefully reprogram, the microcontroller used in an RJ Tianye battery charger (see images of control board PCB).
The MCU appears to be TSSOP-20 with 
pin 7 V_ss 
pin 9 V_dd 
pin 17 dig. in (SW) 
pins 1,2,8,10,16 dig. out (misc) 
pins 11-15 dig. out (LEDs) 
pins 18-20 dig. out (LCD driver) 
pins 3-6 (an. in) 
These pin connections seem match the STM8S pinout (except for AIN, VCAP and NRST). 
Pins 12-16 are also attached to a JTAG (?) header labelled RST, TMS, TCK, TDO and TDI.


Any hints / suggestions?

@Burglups Yes, the LCD driver is a 1621. However, I am stumped by the smaller IC (below the LCD driver), which is the MCU. My guess is that it is a Chinese 8051 clone with STM8S pinout, but I cannot identify the actual device that also has a full JTAG interface.

@Burglups In the image there are two chips: LCD driver SOP-24 TM1621D, this is not relevant to my question. The other smaller TSSOP-20 chip is an unmarked MCU - this is the one I would like to identify. Yes, the dot is at pin 1, it is a 20 pin package, and the pin numbers listed in my question are correct.
